# ember.js release build under cordova / corber uses incorrect URL's

Tags: cordova, ember.js, ember-cli

Have built an iOS application using ember.js and corber.io which is just Cordova for ember, everything works well when running under the live reload development server.

Now ready to begin testing but the build is not operational. The API server URL used by the application is not correct and neither is the internal resources such as image and css files.

The following has been set in the `environment.js` file

```
if (environment === 'production') {
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://xxxx.com';
   }
if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://xxxx.com';
   }
```

Running `corber build --platform=ios --environment=production` as the documentation suggests and there are no build errors.

There is something simple I am missing here.
What are the steps to get an application ready for the production build?

Comment: Re: internal resources paths - do you have fingerprinting configured in ember-cli-build.js?

Comment: @GarrickCheung Thank you for the suggestion, after investigating the fingerprinting parameters it appears they are enabled by default for the production builds. Great thinking but it has not solved the problem :(